# How can a recurrent layer have several neurons?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

If I understand correctly, one neuron per layer is enough since the layer will just be unrolled through time to accomodate a long sequence.

How can a recurrent layer contain several neurons?

Aren't the neurons in one layer essentially the same if they were unrolled through time?

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks (MLP, CNN, RNN) are expected to have multiple neurons through multiple layers. One neuron per layer is hardly enough and will most likely provide a linear solution to the issue being addressed and its architecture will be too small to deal with any kind of real-life situation.

From Brandon Rohrer's video [Recurrent Neural Networks and LSTM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCUNPb-5EYI&) you can see a very simple structure containing multiple neurons (dots) for a single layer. Imagine this simple model working with only one model? It will prove to perform very poorly.
[image]